# when two Null values are existing in same row but in different columns , how can i get the two column names to a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am beginner to the python progamming. hope you will help me to do my project .

I want to write a code to find Null values and add the column names to new column [ validation ] in my dataframe to identify which columns have null values . but when there are two or more Null values in same row only showing last Null value column in the validation column . i need to get all column names which exist null values in same row . how can i modify my code for that

```
for columns in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[column].isnull()==True,['Validation']]="The value in " + column +" is Null "
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my project purpose is to find Null values in a data frame and identify where is the null value exist using column name. this is apply for each column in data frame . when there are are two null values in same column only last null value column name is showing. i want to get all null value column names to that

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html):**

```
df['last_nan']=df.notnull().replace(True,np.nan).T.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)
```